# ReSharper: Fix across solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, jetbrains-ide

Below I have added a screenshot to explain the issue. I am trying to fix certain warnings across solution, not just in a single file. It's really hard to fix them across solution when you're editing an old project with 1,000+ files and you've got 1000+ warnings that could simply be fixed in a matter of minutes, but I've been juggling with them for days.

Is there a way to enable ReSharper option to fix across solution? Or fix across folder even. This happens with a lot of issues, "Remove redundant initializer", "Remove case 0", and "Convert body to LINQ"

[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: Reason for down voting?

Comment: It's due to you're asking help over a software functionality it's nothing do with any coding issue. But I would like to suggest using one of other SO sites ex: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Does ReSharper has similar functionality to IntelliJ IDEA `Code | Inspect Code...`? There it runs all inspections on current/selected file(s) and folders showing all the issues it found. It then allows to quick fix specific issue in all places at once (if invoked on grouping node and not specific occurrence). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-inspection-results.html?search=inspect Maybe something like that exist in ReSharper as well?

Comment: @Sand I disagree, there are only 14 questions tagged with `Resharper` on superuser.com, as opposed to 4,111 on stackoverflow.com. This question relates to a tool used by programmers to help fix coding issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Resharper settings from Resharper Options menu.
Go to :

```
Resharper --> Options --> Code Inspection --> Inspection Severity.
```

Choose C# or VB.Net as per your project language then find "Language Usage Opportunities" and change the settings for "Convert body to LINQ" from 'Warning' to 'Hint'.

Your other problems are also can be fix in similar manner.

Comment: So changing it to 'Hint' will allow me to replace across solution?

Comment: @q1492431 try it first. It will remove the resharper warnings across solution. But the warnings from Visual Studio still shown.